# Present perfect continuous and past continuous

Tags: past-continuous, present-perfect-progressive

> A:"This lesson was so boring, the teacher has been talking/was talking all the time. 
>   B: "How would you know, you have been sleeping/were sleeping all the time".

If the lesson had just finished and we were heading out which would be better?

Comment: The present perfect designates a **present** state derived from the past eventuality. The speakers are presumably no longer bored or sleeping, so there is no reason to cast this in the perfect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need for 'this!' If A and B are talking about some lesson that has ***just*** finished, you can use 'the.' However, note that if you are using past tense, 'that' is used and not 'this.'

*has/have been* is used to talk about an action that has some starting point **and** it is continued *even now.* This is **not** the case here. So,

> A: The lesson was so boring, the teacher *was* talking all the time 
>  B: How would you know? You *were* sleeping all the time!

Comment: Would you say the same in this other situation? Me and my friend are waiting for another friend of ours to get out of the bathroom once they are out I say:"You have been/were in there for ages, what were you doing?"

Comment: Of course yes, 'we have been waiting...' because *you are still there'. We often say - I have been waiting for you for past two hours. As I said 'have/has been something' means from one point of time till now. What 'were' you doing inside...is fine.

Comment: Yesterday I was reading a book and in the same situation "were" was used. This person was at school and once they got out the other friend said"you were there for a long time" or something along these lines. Now I'm even more confused

Comment: Okay, let me try! 'were/was' talks about an event that occurred once. Have/has been talks about the same event *but* it is continued till now. *'I was waiting for you'* simply means that it is *not now; not a second back.* On the other hand, *I have been waiting for you* means you just arrived and I'm telling you that I am here for whatever time...

Comment: But in this case "you were there for a long time" has pretty much the same meaning as "you have been there for a long time".I don't know why were was used though.

Comment: No, it's not like that. If you are in the US and talking to me over the phone, I may say, "Oh, you have been there (the US) for a long time!" In other case, if we are in Australia talking to each other *in person*, I may say, "Oh, you were there (the US) for a long time!"